# Functional Onscreen keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, multi-touch

Is there a better ubuntu keyboard app than Onboard, one that is a decent competitor to the features of Android or Microsoft virtual keyboards?  Specifically, I'd expect:

- Multi-touch: so you can hold shift with one finger, and hit a key with another. (Onboard lacks)
- Word completion/suggestion, with suggested words above keyboard.
- Intelligent autohide.  This is present in onboard with accessibility settings, but far from perfect.  It would be better if, like Android/Windows8, the item in the foreground moved or resized as the keyboard appeared, so the box you're typing in isn't obscured by the keyboard.
- Swype-like behavior to guess words by a path across the keyboard.

Without these features, I really find a virtual keyboard a difficult replacement.

I found this great chart via the [Florence Virtual Keyboard site](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/alternatives.html):

```
Table 1. Keyboards features+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| keyboard | transparency | auto hide | auto click | scanning | word completion |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| Florence | Yes          | Yes       | Yes        | No       | No              |
| GOK      | No           | Yes       | Yes        | Yes      | Yes             |
| XVKBD    | No           | No        | Yes        | No       | Yes             |
| Onboard  | No           | No        | Yes        | No       | No              |
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

However, the suggestions like Gok which appear to have a lot to offer, seem to [be 404 links](http://www.gok.ca/gok) and are [dead in the repos](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gok/).

With all the windows 8 machines that have touch pads, there must be some very slick open source apps for this now, right?  Quite frankly, I'd even buy a non-free one if it could mimic Android well.  (And there are a ton in the google play store, so this might not be too hard?)

Comment: The Android keyboard is USELESS - unless you use [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). Anyway, is this for Ubuntu (Desktop), or Ubuntu Touch? GOK is Gnome Onscreen Keyboard - help page [here](https://developer.gnome.org/accessibility-devel-guide/3.2/id421331.html.en). I guess now it now is implemented inside Gnome 3, or it might been called something else.

Comment: So, if I were to try out 14.04 or something, I should expect a better keyboard than 12.04 had?

Comment: That is not always the case. I have just installed a newer version of another operating system, and by default it use Gnome 3.10. After 5 minutes of using it, I tried persuaded that operating system to think it was the older release I had been previously using, so I could install Gnome 3.8... Anyway, the on-screen keyboard Gnome comes with is not particularly good, and has to be activated in the Accessibility settings, and then in the Notification bar... If it had something like Android's detect text-field thing, it would be fairly good though.

Comment: Above chart is wrong, maybe outdated. Though I agree with you, Ubuntu deserves better virtual keyboard but Onboard is the best among them. There is also Caribou virtual keyboard that can autohide, you might confuse it with Onboard?

Comment: Please. Somebody .  I have to boot android when I want to use my 2in1 in tablet mode because the Onboard keyboard being the best one there is at the moment is extremely lacking necessary functionality for tablet use such as swype input and voice input and emoji. I wish so much that we could use the android keyboard on linux. It has everything. We need swype input. It takes years to tap type one letter at a time. We need voice input and emoji all packages nicely like the android keyboards do.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Maliit onscreen keyboard, try this install method, go to [this website](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/universe/m/maliit-keyboard/install/index.html.).

Comment: This is presently a dead link.